# Update object foreign key with query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, sql-update

I want to make an update of my foreign key associated with the same table that is an object with query.

I can insert a new data(question and foreign key) like this

```
public void insert_question(String question, int left, int right) throws HibernateException
    {
        try
        {
            Session session = getSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Nodes node = new Nodes();
            Nodes leftNode = new Nodes();
            Nodes rightNode = new Nodes();

            node.setQuestion(question); 

            leftNode.setId_node(left);
            node.setLeft(leftNode);

            rightNode.setId_node(right);
            node.setRight(rightNode);

            session.saveOrUpdate(node);
            tx.commit();
            session.close();
```

But i can't update a existing data with this method

```
public void update(int last_left_id, int new_left_id)
    {
        try
        {
            Session session = getSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Nodes leftNode = new Nodes();
            Nodes node = new Nodes();

            leftNode.setId_node(last_left_id);
            node.setLeft(leftNode);


            Query query = getSession().createQuery("update Nodes set left_id = :left_id"+" where id = :id" );
            query.setParameter("left_id", leftNode);
            query.setParameter("id", new_left_id);
            int result = query.executeUpdate();

            session.close();
```

With the first method my foreign keys are inserted into my table.
But with the second method, i can't update my a existing foreign key

Here is my errors

```
Grave: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`akinator`.`node`, CONSTRAINT `node_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`left_id`) REFERENCES `node` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
Grave: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute update query
```

How i could do ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are your parameters correct? query.setParameter("left_id", leftNode);            query.setParameter("id", new_left_id);, shouldn't that be query.setParameter("left_id", new_left_id);
            query.setParameter("id", leftNode);

Comment: For query.setParameter("id", new_left_id), i'm sure. It's a simple integer. For the second, i'm not sure ! i copied the insert method. I do not see how to deal with query

Comment: The error code is telling you that you are trying to set the foreign key to an id that doesn't exist, check that the variables passed to your query are correct

Comment: yes that was it ! For testing I put the values ​​in crude and the values were false :(. Now i have not the errors but my update is not executed. In eclipse, hibernate tell me "Infos: Hibernate: update node set left_id=? where id=?"

Answer (score 0):

The case when you can't do anything by code, then it is best to run sql patch . Actually In our application, we are doing same things by running scripts on startup. So This way may solve your problem.

For example,  If you want to add foreign key on order table then write a program to execute this script on startup action using java.

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
```

This my not help but I suggest you we can do it using this way. :)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, now i have no errors. I see my update is executed but it is not in db.